# Executing a python script from inittab not as root

Tags: python, root

I have a python script which I would like to launch from inittab, shown below

s1:respawn:/home/a_user/app/script.py

I believe initab executes as root, so the a_user's envrinment is not available

The script needs to know "a_user" home directory for ini file settings and log file storage. I would like to avoid hard coding these paths in my script. Is it possible to execute this script as a_user and not a root? If this is possible would a_user HOME environment variable  be available?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use `runuser` (or the distro's equvalent) to run it as a different user. `runuser` does change `$HOME`, but other similar commands may not.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that and it doesnt work, i.e su -a_user /path_to_script/scripy.py

Comment: Thanks, I'm running opensuse and it doesn have the runuser command and both su and sudo dont work

Answer (score 1):

you could copy python binary to python-suid,
chown it to user you want to run scripts as and chown u+s python-suid

then in script #!/usr/bin/python-suid